# Epiphany Browser Kiosk/Full Screen but has a 1px white border

Tags: web-browsers

I've got a Raspberry Pi 2 running Epiphany Browser in fullscreen mode by running the following in a shell script on startup.

```
sudo matchbox-window-manager -use_cursor no -use_titlebar no &

sudo -u pi epiphany-browser -a --profile ~/.config file:///home/pi/index.html
```

This works really well except there is a 1px white border around the entire screen/window of the browser. I've tried using overscan and negative 1 to spill it off the screen but my monitor doesn't seem to accept negative numbers, accepts positive numbers so I can see a black border but of course I don't want that. I'd rather sort the issue by removing the border rather than using something like overscan if possible.

Im sure this has only started in the last few months since having run a `sudo apt-get update` on the Pi but not 100% sure.

Any thoughts would be really appreciated.

Comment: Does your monitor have its own hardware controls for adjusting the image size? Might be easiest to sidestep the problem.

Comment: Sadly that isn't an option, im planning to deploy lots of these to customers who'll use different makes/models of TVs and monitors. Thanks for the suggestion though